# Read a sequence in reverse

Tags: unix, sequence, reverse

I have a problem here:

if i have a chain sequence as below, how to read this strand in reverse (unix)?

input : CCTTTATCTTTATCTAG
desired output : GATCTATTTCTATTTCC

Thanks for the help. =)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are using "unix" as a synonym for "reverse"...?

Comment: sorry for confused you. I just wanted to know is they any simple command in unix to get a reverse read of a chain of sequence as above. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "CCTTTATCTTTATCTAG" | rev
GATCTATTTCTATTTCC
```

rev is what you want.

A related command is tac which reverses the line order of a file.

Comment: @amine, you need to google a bit and use the above command as answered by Shawn